Why PIT (8253) Mode 0 doesn't work well on VMware workstation 17
I tried to make a music player to play wave file through PC speaker, I've already made a program that can play 8bit wave file in Dos Box. However, when I try to run the program in Dos 7.1 in VMware, it plays no sounds.
After checking it, I found that:
PIT in VMware workstation doesn't work well. When the Data port(0x42) is not rewritten, PIT in VMware working in channel 2 mode 0 provide more than one rising edge (which is incorrect), while PIT in Dos Box only provides one (which is correct).
*And this problem is not produced by Dos 7.1 I installed because PIT doesn't work well in MBR code (written in NASM by myself) either.
To reproduce the problem, compile this program in TC and run it in DOS Box and VMware.
/*
Use PWM to make the sounds more "colorful"
*/



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAMBUFFER 8*1024*sizeof(char)
#define DEFAULTFREQ 54

void interrupt ( *int8org)();
unsigned short bufferInUse = 0;
unsigned short cambioBuff = 0;
unsigned char *doblebuffer[2];
unsigned short posBuffer = 0;
unsigned char byte;
unsigned char freqtab[256];
unsigned short freq;
unsigned short count = 0, ass = 50;

void interrupt PITinthandle (__CPPARGS)
{
    if(posBuffer == TAMBUFFER)
    {
        bufferInUse = 1-bufferInUse;
        posBuffer = 0;
        cambioBuff = 1;
    }
/*Load a byte if it is not at the tail of the buffer*/
    byte = doblebuffer[bufferInUse][posBuffer++];
/*Rewrite channel 2 data port*/
    outportb(0x42, (int)freqtab[byte]);
    outportb(0x20, 0x20);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE * audioFile;
    unsigned short PCM;
    unsigned short track;
    short int bitWidth;
    long int freqInHZ;
    unsigned short int terminade = 0;
    unsigned short int legalWAV = 0;
    unsigned short int i;

    doblebuffer[0] = (unsigned char *) malloc(TAMBUFFER);
    doblebuffer[1] = (unsigned char *) malloc(TAMBUFFER);

    switch(argc)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("ERROR");
            return 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            freq = DEFAULTFREQ;
            break;
        case 3:
            freq = 1193180/atoi(argv[2]);
            break;
    }
    if('.' == argv[1][strlen(argv[1])-4] &&
            'w' == argv[1][strlen(argv[1])-3] &&
            'a' == argv[1][strlen(argv[1])-2] &&
            'v' == argv[1][strlen(argv[1])-1])
        legalWAV = 1;

    audioFile = fopen (argv[1],"rb");
    if (audioFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error enter a file name");
        return 1;
    }

    if(legalWAV)
    {
        fseek(audioFile, 20, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&PCM, 1, sizeof(short int), audioFile);
        fread(&track, 1, sizeof(short int), audioFile);
        fseek(audioFile, 34, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&bitWidth, 1, sizeof(short int), audioFile);
        if(PCM == 1 && track == 1 && bitWidth == 8)
        {
            fseek(audioFile , 24, SEEK_SET);
            fread(&freqInHZ, 1, sizeof(long int), audioFile);
            freq = 1193180/freqInHZ;
            fseek(audioFile, 44, SEEK_SET);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error not 8bit, 1track, PCM WAV");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    fread(doblebuffer[0], 1, TAMBUFFER, audioFile);
    fread(doblebuffer[1], 1, TAMBUFFER, audioFile);

    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        freqtab[i] = (i*freq/256) + 1;

/*Setup our INT handle*/
    int8org = getvect(8);
    setvect(8, PITinthandle);

/*Program PIT, make it provide rising edge in output. FORMAT: channel 2,mode 0, low byte only*/
    outportb(0x43, 0x90);
    outportb(0x43, 0x16);
    
/*Program PIT, make it INT in channel 0. FORMAT: channel 0, mode 3 low byte only, interrupt at the speed of wave sampling */
    outportb(0x40, freq);

/*Enable speaker*/
    byte = inportb(0x61);
    outportb(0x61, byte|0x03);

/*Play until any key is pressed or music is over*/
    while(peekb(0x40,0x1A) == peekb(0x40,0x1C) && !terminade)
    {
        if(cambioBuff)
        {
/*load the wave file until it is finish*/
            if(!fread(doblebuffer[1-bufferInUse], 1, TAMBUFFER, audioFile)) terminade = 1;
            cambioBuff = 0;
        }
    }

    byte = inportb(0x61);
    outportb(0x61, byte&0xFC);

    outportb(0x40, 0x00);

    setvect(8, int8org);

    free(doblebuffer[0]);
    free(doblebuffer[1]);

    fclose(audioFile);

    return 0;
}


How can I make this program run properly in VMware? and How to make PIT in VMware work properly?
